# Basis of field extension of rational number that is closed square root without axiom of choice

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, irrational-numbers, axiom-of-choice

Consider a field extension $F$ of the rational numbers. $F$ contains all numbers that can be constructed using square root. In this field, there are the regular rational numbers such as 1, 2, 3, $\frac{42}{13}$, etc. There are square roots such as $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{\frac{42}{13}}$, etc. It does not* contain cubic roots, i.e., $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\sqrt[3]{3}$, $\sqrt[3]{\frac{42}{13}}$. The square root can be applied iteratively. This means that $\sqrt[4]{3} = \sqrt{\sqrt{3}}$ is in the set. The square root operation can only be applied a finite number of times, i.e., constructions that involve the limit of $a_i=\sqrt{42+a_{i-1}}$ or similar sequences are not considered.

(*I assume that F does not contain cubic roots. If one can show that a cubic root can somehow be written as combination of square roots then F would contain cubic roots. This would be valuable information to me, if my assumption is wrong here.)

Can somebody provide a constructive (i.e. no axiom of choice) construction of a basis of this field as rational vector space? If $F$ has no basis without axiom of choice would also be an interesting result.

My objective is to perform exact geometric computations that involve length computations in a computer. These computations may be very slow. The idea is to represent the numbers of $F$ by storing the coefficients of this basis. This is the reason why I do not want to use the axiom of choice. I need to know how the basis actually looks like to be able to perform computations on it. A statement of the form "if you believe the axiom of choice, then the basis exists but nobody knows how it looks" is not helpful. That is not something one can implement in a computer.

Comment: So $F$ is the field of [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)?

Comment: @Ihf Yes, I think that is exactly what I had in mind. I did not know that it has a name. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two fine points here.

1. There is always a canonical, countable, field which is the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ closed under $\sqrt\cdot$. Since this field is countable, simply enumerate it, and recursively construct a basis. Done and done.
2. It is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that there is a field which is **a** closure of $\Bbb Q$ under $\sqrt\cdot$, but it is not well-orderable. I'm not sure if this field doesn't have a basis, but that stands to reason to expect that it doesn't. If it does, though, this basis is certainly not well-orderable. So working with it from a computational point of view is ... odd, at best.

Since you're saying "this field", it seems that you have in mind the first option. To see that it is countable more explicitly, note that every polynomial of the form $x^2-p=0$ has at most two roots and there are countably many such polynomials; using the fact that $\Bbb C$ can be linearly ordered (as a set!), this is a countable union of pairs; this defines a canonical enumeration of the smallest field in which $\sqrt q$ exists for each rational $q$. Now repeat this, using said canonical enumeration to kickstart the next step in the recursion.

After going through all the finite steps of the recursion, you are left with a countable sequence of countable sets that are equipped with canonical enumerations, and therefore their union is indeed countable.

Comment: I do not understand. You say that there are countably many equations of form $x^2-p=0$ where $p\in\mathbb{C}$. My understanding is that $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable. I therefore believe that there are uncountably many such equations.

EDIT: or is $p\in \mathbb{Q}$? In this case, you will not have an equation to cover $\sqrt[4]{42}$ I believe.

Comment: No, there are countably many polynomials of the form $x^2-p=0$ where $p\in\Bbb Q$. Because you're interested in the case where $p$ is rational. And if you keep reading, you'll see that $\sqrt[4]{42}$ is $\sqrt{\sqrt{42}}$, so in the recursive construction of the field, this will be added in the second step.

Comment: Ok, now I understood your construction. :) Essentially, you are saying that every every number $x\in F$ can be written as the solution of finite system of equations. For $x=\sqrt[4]{42}$, the equations are:
$y^2 - 42 = 0$, $y\ge 0$, $x^2 - y = 0$, $x \ge 0$
Next you argue that these equations systems are countable and so $F$ is countable.

How do you represent $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}^4$ this way?

To have a basis, we need a unique representation, i.e., the equality of the equation system must imply equality of the represented number. Why is this the case?

Comment: No, to have a basis we need to satisfy the conditions for a theorem that lets us prove that there is a basis. If you ***really*** want to find it explicitly, it's a terrible exercise in recursion. Build the field by recursion, then use the enumeration of $F$ to construct a basis using recursion.

Comment: Let $B={b_1,b_2,\ldots}$ be a basis. For every $x\in F$ there must be a finite sets $I\in \mathbb{N}$ with coefficients $c:I\mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x = \sum_{i\in I} c(i)\cdot b_i$. $I$ and $c$ must be unique. If they are not unique, then $B$ is not a basis. You gave a method to enumerate the elements of $F$. What is $B$?

Comment: Once you enumerate $F$, go through the elements. One by one. If the current element is not in the span of what you previous collected, keep it; otherwise throw it out and move on. At the end, the elements you collect are a basis for the field. This is the standard proof by recursion that a space has a basis. Choice is only coming into the picture when we need to choose what is the next element to consider. But here we have an enumeration, so there's no need to use AC.

Comment: How do you check whether a new element is in the span of the already enumerated?

Comment: It is or it isn't. Mathematics is not computation.